# If $A(x)^{T}A(x) = C$, then $A(x) = O\widetilde{C}$ with $O$ Orthogonal?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Let $A(x)$ be an $n \times m$ matrix-valued function of the vector variable $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be a fixed positive semidefinite matrix. Is the following bidirectional statement true?

$$
A(x)^{T}A(x) = C\;\;\;\forall x \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad A(x) = O(x)\tilde{C}
$$
for some $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $O(x)$ some $\tilde{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ such that $\tilde{C}^{T}\tilde{C} = C$.

(The $\Longleftarrow$ implication is obvious; my question really concerns the $\Longrightarrow$ implication).

Comment: What has the variables $x$ for to do with this?

Comment: The matrix $A$ is a function of the vector $x$, and the matrix equation $A(x)^{T}A(x) = C$ holds for all values of $x$.

Comment: I see, the question is a bit vague in that regard. You might want to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=VDW$ be the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition). If you re-write the equality $A=VDW$ as $A=(VW)W^TDW$, we get the polar decomposition $A=UM$, with $M$ positive-semidefinite and $U$ orthogonal. Since 
$$
M=(M^TM)^{1/2}=(A^TU^TUA)^{1/2}=(A^TA)^{1/2}=C^{1/2}, 
$$
the matrix $M$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I think theres a problem with this argument; I am looking for $\tilde{C}$ to be independent of $x$, and this construction would yield $\tilde{C}(x)$ since $W$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I have edited to show how the argument produces the right matrices.